# Problem to upload csv file in server using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data

I tried from lots of days,  first I tried MultipartRequest of [Volley Plus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus)
 It worked, but now days I am facing 403 error **(BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for)** in my code while I did not change any thing. After I am trying to use Volley Custom MultipartRequest from [here](https://demonuts.com/upload-image-to-server-in-android-using-multipart-volley/) and others of stackoverflow answer but I found same means all answer for Image Upload by multipart request.

**Volley Plus Request Code**

```
     SimpleMultiPartRequest request = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        request.addFile("file", "fileUri");
        request.addStringParam("user", "userValue");
//        request.addMultipartParam("body", "text/plain", "some text");

        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        mRequestQueue.add(request);
        mRequestQueue.start();
```

**POSTMAN SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Code of volley plus or Custom MultiPart Request. which one do you want?

Comment: volley plush request

Comment: have you tried on the postman   to verify API

Comment: @MilanPansuriya yes bro its works fine on postman. If have any solution for upload csv file to server you can suggest me.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of postman and Volly multipart code

Comment: I think you are passing data but your API required file

Comment: @MilanPansuriya For volley plus request I added that code on my question and also attached screen shot of postman. If  you want code of volley custom multipart request you can go with here text link on question